# Triadic representation of a positive even integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, number-systems

I want to show that all positive even integers have even number of digit “$1$” in their triadic representation.

An even number is of the form $n = 2k$ with $k\in \mathbb{Z}$.

To find the triadic representation we do the Euclidean division of the number $n$ and $3$ and we consider the remainders to get the triadic representation, right?

First we do $n : 3 = 2k : 3$. Then we have to take cases if $k$ is a multiple of $3$ or not, right?

Comment: Isn't this obvious?  All the other terms in the sum are clearly even so...   Should say, I am assuming that the "triadic representation" means the base $3$ representation.

Comment: Why are all the terms in the sum even? @lulu

Comment: I don't understand what you are unclear on.  Obviously the terms with coefficients $0$ or $2$ are even, right?  So the sum of the powers of $3$ with coefficient $1$ must be even.  A sum of odd terms is even iff there are evenly many terms in the sum.  QED.

Comment: Does the terms with coefficients $0$ or $2$ have to be even because the given number is even? @lulu

Comment: $0$ times anything is $0$, hence even.  $2$ times anything is even.

Comment: Assume you mean ternary ?

Comment: If so @lulu 's argument generalizes. In any odd base the number of odd digits will be odd in an odd number.

Comment: The parity of $a_n\cdot 3^n$ is for all $n$ (including $0$) equal to the parity of $a_n$. Hence the given number is even if and only if the digit sum in base $3$ is even. The only odd digit in base $3$ is $1$, hence the number of ones must be even.